# How to combine two or more proxies?

Tags: proxy

I already use a proxy for my WiFi . Now, in order to use Adblock Plus, I need to change the proxy to localhost:2020 *(as asked by adblock plus)* .

How can I combine the two proxies ?

My phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from : [How To Connect To Other Proxy](https://code.google.com/p/sandrop/wiki/HowToConnectToOtherProxy) 
Developer said : `Root NOT needed on 3.x or higher android OS`.just try it.

[Download SandroProxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy&hl=en) (From Google Play)

**Set Android OS proxy to point to `SandroProxy` :**

Go to `-> Android OS Settings -> Wifi` - *Long click* on active wifi connection. Menu will appear. `Choose Modify network`.

On the bottom there is option Advanced settings. Turn it on. Scroll down.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Set proxy to manual, localhost 8020 for Drony or 8008 for SandroProxy.
Set SandroProxy to connect to other proxy:

Start SandroProxy and go to wizard if it doesn't appear. `(Log tab -> Menu->Wizard)`

Select Connect to other proxy
Set (tcpip or hostname) and port to proxy, username (domain\user or realm\user) and password

> Don't forget to activate with Active checkbox and click on Set button

[image]
[image]
[image]